# Default content of /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf from Raspbian

Tags: dhcp

Could some kind soul please post the default content of the `dhclient.conf` file from `/etc/dhcp/` as I've managed to delete mine :/

Comment: Please thank people using upvote mechanism and mark correct answer. Also no need to sign your question. We can see who you are. :) +1 good question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fetch the original file yourself. The Raspbian package repository can be found [here](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main). The package you are looking for can be found like this:

```
dpkg -S /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Which yields the package `isc-dhcp-client`. It can be found under the letter `i` in the package repository: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/isc-dhcp/. You can download the current version (`isc-dhcp-client_4.2.2.dfsg.1-5+deb70u3_armhf.deb` as of today) and inspect it after download. I use the Midnight Commander (`mc` in a terminal) to do this. Just navigate to the deb-package and hit return in `mc`. You will see the contents then.

The original file can then be found at `CONTENTS/etc/dhcp/` inside of the package. You can even hit the `F5` key to copy the file out of the package.

This strategy works with most packages that come with default configurations.

Answer (score 3):

here it comes:

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#   dhcp3-client package.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

#send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
send host-name = gethostname();
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;

#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}

#lease {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.33.137.200;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.33.137.250;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I always recommend when editing files is to take a backup first. One nice way of doing this is by using a version control software, such as "rcs". Once this is installed, before editing a system file, such as dhclient.leases, simply type before editing it:

```
sudo ci -l dhclient.leases
```

It will ask for a comment each time you do this, and you can "Check-In" this file each time there's a version you want to store for potential later retrieval.